# Add multiple parameters in URL asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently trying to send 2 parameters through an URL in ASP.NET. I have been able to successfully send across 1 parameter. I am now wanting to learn how to send 2 across.

I am wanting to also send another ID as well that links to Favourite_ID similar to what is happening below with Recipe_ID

***ASP.NET***

```
<asp:HyperLink Runat ="server" NavigateUrl ='<%#"RecipePage?id=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Recipe_ID").ToString()%>' ID="Hyperlink1"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Recipe_Name")%></asp:HyperLink></asp>
```

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+url+add+query+parameters

Comment: Prepare Url like www.domain.com/search?parameter1=value&parameter2=value2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:hyperlink
runat="server"
id="hlReceipt"
navigateurl='<%# String.Format("RecipePage.aspx?id={0}&name={1}", Eval("Receipt_ID"), Eval("Receipt_Name")) %>'
text='<%# Eval("Receipt_title") %>'>
</asp:hyperlink>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:HyperLink Runat ="server" NavigateUrl ='<%#"RecipePage?id=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Recipe_ID").ToString()+"&YourId="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "YourId")%>' ID="Hyperlink1"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Recipe_Name")%></asp:HyperLink></asp>
```

You can place you id name in place of YourId and can add multiple ids like above